# react get all children refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refs

I have a component that renders dynamic children, each of these children need to have a ref assigned to them e.g. `ref={'childID' + index}`

once the children have loaded I then need a way to loop over of the children and get their refs.

any way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need their refs?

Comment: Because I have a single component (a toggle switch) in the parent which renders the components with refs. I use the refs the call a function in the child component when the switch is toggled.

I have it working now, but it only works on the last element rendered by the parent, so i think the issue is that multiple children can be rendered so they each need a unique ref.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to loop through `this.refs` object using `Object.keys`.

```
Object.keys(this.refs).forEach(key =>
  const ref = this.refs[key];
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback style for the `ref` prop to collect all the refs.

Here's a rough example of how this would look.

```
var refs = {};

function refCollector(id) {
  return function(element) {
    refs[id] = element;

    if(allRefsCollected()) {
      // do some work with all refs
    }
  }
}

function allRefsCollected() {
  return Object.keys(refs).length >= children.length;
}

return children.map((Child, index) => {
  return <Child ref={refCollector(index)} />;
});
```

When `allRefsCollected` returns true, you'll know that all the children have been rendered and `refs` will be an object, mapping `id` to `element`.